# Weird behaviour with lxml getiterator()

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following XML document:

```
<x>
  <a>Some text</c>
  <b>Some text 2</b>
  <c>Some text 3</c>
</x>
```

I want to get the text of all the tags, so I decided to use `getiterator()`.

My problem is, it adds up blank lines for a reason I can't understand. Consider this:

```
>>> for text in document_root.getiterator():
...     print text.text
... 


Some text
Some text 2
Some text 3
```

Notice the two extra blank lines before 'Some text'. What is the reason for this? If I pass a tag to the `getiterator()` method, there are no blank lines, as it should be.

```
>>> for text in document_root.getiterator('a'):
...     print text.text
... 
Some text
```

So my question is, what is causing those extra blank lines in case I pass `getiterator()` without a tag and how do I remove them?

Comment: I also tried doing: `if text.text == '\n': continue` so that it would skip the blank lines, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `lxml.etree` will regard empty text between tags as the textual content for that tag and in your case the whitespace being displayed comes from `<x>`. If you want a parser that ignores the whitespace you'll want to do something like:

```
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)

tree = etree.XML("""\
    <x>
      <a>Some text</a>
      <b>Some text 2</b>
      <c>Some text 3</c>
    </x>
""", parser)

for node in tree.iter():
    if node.text == None: continue
    print node.text
```

Note how `node.text` will return None if there is no text at all. Also note that [the API documentation for lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getiterator) states that `getiterator()` is deprecated in favor of `iter()`.

For more information see [The lxml.etree Tutorial: Parser objects](http://codespeak.net/lxml/tutorial.html#parser-objects).

Comment: little remark: `None` is unique, so you can (and, in my opinion, should) use `if node.text is None` directly. My two cents!

Answer (score 0):

Although Im not sure, I would assume it's trying to read text within < x >.

Anyhow, what's wrong with

```
for text in document_root.getiterator():
    if text.strip() == '': continue
    print text
```

Comment: Aah. I forgot I could use `strip()` too.

Comment: It solves my problem but the question of why it happens remains.

Comment: Because the element <x> contains text, in this case it's just whitespace but that's still text nonetheless.